# How to add custom styling in pageproperties in AEM

Tags: aem

I have template and page properties. I had added custom tab to page properties, where I need to modify the height and width of page property tab. How can I add custom styling to page properties. I using AEM 6.5 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the change globally, on all the dialogs, you can always write a .CSS file with the category `cq.authoring.dialog`.

If however, you want it to be specific to that dialog, you can add a JCR property in the page properties dialog node:

`extraClientlibs` -> {the value would be the name of categories for your JS/CSS files}

And it should pick up the styling/scripting from there.

Comment: was this helpful?